# Git - push after feature branch rebase

Tags: git, git-branch, gerrit, branching-and-merging

I have a git repo and currently I'm working in the feature branch.

I have something like that:

```
dev: ---1--2--3--
                \
fb:              --f1
```

While I was working on my feature branch, more commits to dev happened, so I rebased on it and now sha of my commits have changed

```
dev: ---1--2--3--4--5----
                      \
fb:                    --f1(another)
```

So now I can't push it to the remote feature branch because SHAs are invalid. I **can't push with force**, cause it is prohibited by the server.

So, what is the correct workflow in such a case, what should I do?

Answer (score 1):

My suggestion would be either `merge remote/dev into local/fb` or `delete remote/fb` then push local/fb with git history.

- Undo rebase and **merge remote/dev into local/fb**.

  ```
  # undo rebase: reset your local/fb with remote/fb
  $ git checkout fb
  $ git reset --hard origin/fb

  # merge and push to remote/fb 
  $ git pull origin dev
  $ git push origin fb
  ```
- **Delete remote/fb** branch, then push your **local/fb with history**.

  ```
  $ git push origin --delete fb      # delete remote/fb branch
  $ git push origin fb
  ```

Answer (score 0):

You can for example do one of:

- delete the remote branch, then push your local branch
- push your local branch to a newly named remote branch
- undo the rebase and do a merge instead
- convince the repository hoster to allow force-pushes, then force-push your local branch

Answer (score 0):

It depends on your overall workflow as intended by your company/team. It is however, possible that they haven't fully thought it out.

Preventing forced-push on all branches, and requiring feature branches to be rebased are contradictory. Both things can be reasonable parts of a workflow, but not the same workflow.

**Two Options**

If forced pushes to feature branches *must* be denied within your company, the consequence is that you can't rebase those feature branches. You will need to preform non-fastforward merges instead.

If your company expects you to rebase your feature branches, then they must make the repo accept forced-pushes to those feature branches. Having git deny forced pushes on only certain branches instead of all branches is trivially easy.

**Sloppy workarounds**

You can of course delete your feature branches every time you rebase, and create a new branch each time. This is very sloppy, and will results in a ridiculous number of unnecessary branches. Your company/team should think through their workflow strategy to avoid this sort of thing.